# Using public docker image in azure Container

Tags: azure, docker, server, redis, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a multi-container web app to azure. When deploying it fails to pull the redis:alpine docker image saying it has unauthorized access. This is a public docker image so it should not require authentication. Other posts talking about this recommend using `docker logout` but this is not an option on the Azure server.

My current solution would be to build the redis:alpine image locally push it to our teams docker hub with the other docker images I create and use that. On this point I am a bit stuck since I can't seem to get the Dockerfile for redis:alpine

This might not be the best solution so hopefully someone over here can help me out

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are trying to deploy ? From the Portal, ARM/Bicep, cli..?

Comment: I am deploying using an Azure pipeline. This pipeline pushes our own image to the docker server of my team and builds an artifact the gets deployed to Azure

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. In the azure pipeline, I pull the public image while logged out and push it to my team's Docker registry after logging in. There probably is a better solution for this but for now this will do

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).